# Formatting output of R

Tags: r, plot, gnu, output

I want to plot the output of R on GNU plot. E.g., I have a matrix `x` storing integers, and I make matrix `y` as `y<- x^2`.

Now GNU plot requires input in input data file in following format:

```
x1 y1
x2 y2
x3 y3
... and so on...
```

How can I produce this output file from R?

Specifically, how do I remove indices that are shown in output of R and arrange the elements of a matrix vertically?

Comment: Try t(x) or t(matrix) to arrange them vertically

Comment: read the `?write.table`. Look at options `col.names`, `row.names`, `sep`, `quote`. Also, if you are using R, why do you want to use GNU plot?

Comment: ...or use R to do the plotting. I like having just one tool to work with. Especially when using `ggplot2` you have a very powerful graphing environment in R.

Comment: I added some example plots that R produces.

Answer (score 3):

It is not entirely clear to me if you want to plot two vectors against each other, or do something with a matrix. I assume the first. Let's create some example data:

```
x = 1:10
y = x^2    
z = cbind(x, y)
```

Next, we put this in a file:

```
write.table(z, file = "/tmp/spam", row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE)
```

and if we check the output:

```
$ cat /tmp/spam
1 1
2 4
3 9
4 16
5 25
6 36
7 49
8 64
9 81
10 100
```

I think this is what you need. Alternatively, just do:

```
plot(y~x, z, type = "l")
```

[image]

and avoid GNUplot altogether. Or even better imo, use `ggplot2`:

```
require(ggplot2); theme_set(theme_bw())
qplot(x, y, data = data.frame(z), geom = "line")
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There is a basic set of interface functions between R and gnuplot in the TeachingDemos package, see `?gp.open`.  These may do what you want, or you can look at the code for an example of creating a datafile in the format that gnuplot wants.